# Binding variable not updating with INotifyPropertyChanged and setting DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am writing a simple macro program that you can create macros on and by doing this I wanted to create a user control that would be a new macro editor. Each macro editor has two textboxes. The left one is the keys that you need to press and the right textbox shows the keys that it will output after those first keys are pressed. I used binding for these two textboxes but it seems to not update. It only shows the beginning values.

C#:

```
public MacroControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Thread checkKeys = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CheckKeys));
    checkKeys.Start();
}

private string[] _text = {null,null};
public string[] Text
{
    get { return _text; }
    set
    {
        if(_text != value)
        {
            _text = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}


    private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxIndex = 0;
        Text[TextBoxIndex] = "test";
    }

    private void TextBox_GotFocus_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBoxIndex = 1;
        Text[TextBoxIndex] = "test";
    }

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="250*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="141*"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="109*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
<TextBlock FontSize="20" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="236,12,126.625,11">⟶</TextBlock>
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Text[0]}" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" Background="Transparent" Margin="15"  Grid.Column="0"/>
<TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Text[1]}" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus_1" Background="Transparent" Margin="15"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
```

Comment: You don't seem to change them anywhere...

Comment: I did i just didn't show that. I put text[0] = "test"; and nothing changed

Comment: So... show it then.

Comment: you can't apply the PropertyChange to an array. You must track each text value with a separate property.

Comment: @James an array doesn't notify changes. You could just try an `ObservableCollection` instead, but since you only have two elements, you might want to use two properties instead.

Comment: okay ill try that thank you.

Comment: @James Any luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've mentioned in the comments, arrays don't fire `PropertyChanged` events so your Bindings don't even know you changed the value. A potential workaround would be calling it manually after you change an item:

```
TextBoxIndex = 0;
Text[TextBoxIndex] = "test";
NotifyPropertyChanged("Text[]");
```

And yes, the `[]` are on purpose.

A better approach would be to use two separate properties.

---

Slightly related: If you want your properties to be updated while the user is still entering the text, set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of your Binding to `PropertyChanged`. `TextBox.Text` uses `LostFocus` by default (updates when the TextBox loses focus).

Answer (score 0):

Your property changed event is fired on when `Text` is set.

```
text[0] = "test";
```

This will not call the setter for `Text`. You would need a line starting with `Text =`. That said, a better way would be to actually have two properties, one string for each field. There is no advantage to have an array.

Comment: Oh. Thank you i realise now because i've done this before and done that and it worked.